# How to create stacked bar chart from different data format with altair in python?

Tags: python, pandas, altair

What y-expression should I specify in the following example to create a stacked bar chart? Is there some expression like

```
y="$all-other-columns"
```

or

```
y="$group-of-columns"
```

Or would I need to reshape the data to [long-form](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) to follow the example

https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/stacked_bar_chart.html

and the suggestions in

https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#converting-with-pandas

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'id_foo': 1, 'energy_carrier': 'oil', '2000': 5, '2020': 10},
        {'id_foo': 2, 'energy_carrier': 'electricity', '2000': 10, '2020': 20},
    ]
)

pivot_df = df.pivot_table(
    columns='energy_carrier',
    values=['2000', '2020'],
    aggfunc='sum',
)

plot_colors = ['blue', 'green']

plot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()

colors = alt.Color('energy_carrier:N', scale=alt.Scale(range=plot_colors))

chart = (
    alt.Chart(plot_df)
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        x='index:O',
        #y=?,
        color=colors,
    )
    .properties(width=200)
)

chart.show()
```

[image: Expected]

I want a result like this:

[image]

Related:

[How to use indexed data frames with altair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77993730/how-to-use-indexed-data-frames-with-altair)

Comment: Convert the data frame to long format and then sum the y-axis. `df = df.melt(id_vars=['id_foo','energy_carrier'], value_vars=['2000','2020'], var_name='year')` `alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(size=80).encode(
    x='year',
    y='sum(value)',
    color=colors,
    ).properties(
    width=400
    )`

Comment: I got this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjXFT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Altair prefers the long-form. If you do not want to rehape the data with melt, its possible to use a transform to define a new "variable", for example `value` and apply it for the y-expression:

```
chart = (
    alt.Chart(plot_df)
    .transform_fold(
        ['oil', 'electricity'],
        as_=['energy_carrier', 'value'],
    )
    .mark_line()
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        color=colors,
        x='index:O',
        y='value:Q',
    )
    .properties(width=200)
)

chart.show()
```

Also see

https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#converting-with-fold-transform