# How to use indexed data frames with altair?

Tags: python, pandas, altair

Lets say I have an indexed pandas DataFrame `indexed_df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'id_foo': 1, 'energy_carrier': 'oil', '2000': 5, '2020': 10},
        {'id_foo': 2, 'energy_carrier': 'electricity', '2000': 10, '2020': 20},
    ]
)

indexed_df = df.pivot_table(
    columns='energy_carrier',
    values=['2000', '2020'],
    aggfunc='sum',
)
```

[image]

How can I use this DataFrame with altair and map the index to the x values?

Do I always need to reset the DataFrame to get a named column?

```
x='named_column'
```

Or is there a way to tell altair to use the index?

```
x='$index'
```

I would expect altair to use the index of an indexed DataFrame for x values by default. However, that does not seem to be the case. I tried to use

```
x='index'
```

(or no specification for x) and do not get the results I would expect.

Related:

[How to create stacked bar chart from different data format with altair in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77993663/how-to-create-stacked-bar-chart-with-altair-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Just found

https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#including-index-data

"By design Altair only accesses dataframe columns, not dataframe indices"

Therefore, resetting the index or creating extra named columns from the index seems to be a must with altair.

I created a feature request to support indexed data frames:

https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/3331